# Onvif ptz operation times out

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ip-camera, onvif

I've made a c# app which can control Onvif cameras which it works to an extent. I can discover, connect and control the cameras, however after sending a few (different amount each time) movement commands the camera becomes unresponsive, the error "The operation has timed out" appears and I have to physically restart my camera to use it again.
The code is as follows:

```
        Uri uri = new Uri(String.Format("http://" 
                + ipAddr + "/onvif/" + "{0}", Service));
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create((uri));
        request.KeepAlive = false;
        //WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create((uri));
        request.Method = "POST";

        byte[] b = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(PostData);
        request.ContentLength = b.Length;
        request.Proxy = null;

        request.Timeout = 5000;
        Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream();

        //Send Message
        XmlDocument recData = new XmlDocument();
        try
        {
            lock (_lock)
            {
                using (stream = request.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    if (stream.CanWrite)
                    {
                        stream.Flush();
                        stream.Write(b, 0, b.Length);
                    }
                }
                //Store response
                var response = (HttpWebResponse) request.GetResponse();
                if (response.GetResponseStream() != null)
                {
                    string responsestring = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
                    recData.LoadXml(responsestring);
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
                Thread.Sleep(200);
                stream.Flush();
                IsBusy = false;
                Rec = true;
            }
        }
```

The code hangs on the var response line. Using wireshark I see that there is no response coming back from the camera. 
Is there a better method I can use to send the requests or a way that I can ignore the responses?

Comment: Why are you doing this manually instead of using "Add service reference" from Visual Studio? They seem to have a nice and friendly WSDL available.

Comment: I'm fairly new to this kind of programming and didn't know about that, guess I'll go check it out